# Custom Java annotation that calls a REST API

Tags: java, annotations, artifact

I would like to create a Java annotation `@Ping` that sends a `POST` request to a REST API that I deployed in a Docker container.

So far, I created this annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Ping {
    String endpoint();
}
```

As you can see, I would like this annotation to be based on methods. This method will allow me to give a status (available or unavailable) to my other services.

I also would like to store this code as a Maven artifact on my own repo, where I will add a couple more annotations, so that I can use it on my other services.

I have seen a couple tutorials but couldn't figure out how to externalize this behavior, and I couldn't have this working in the first place anyway.

From what I understand, now I need a handler that contains the logic (i.e. that sends a `POST` request to my API), but I am not sure how to do that.
Any chance you can help me get started on this? Is an annotation a good idea to do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: annotations don't really "do"  things on their own. what exactly are you looking for? that when the method you annotated is being called, a rest call is made? You'll need to implement some AOP.
Yes, it can be completely externalize this, but I don't really see the point, frankly.

Comment: So the first thing I needed was kind of a ping, every time my method is called, I wanted to ping my API for analytic purposes. Then the idea was to create a couple more annotations I would need, like `@RequireHeader` to force using an HTTP header I use, along with `@RequiresHttps` to force the usage of HTTPS over HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method level annotation and Use AOP to write a logic that will call your rest api

```
@Around("execution(@Ping * *(..))")
public void entr(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
 System.out.println("before method");
 joinPoint.proceed();
 System.out.println("after method");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Urvil Joshi's answer, considering I didn't want to have add a Spring dependency, I created a `PingAspect.aj` file with this content:

```
public aspect PingAspect {

    pointcut hasPingAnnotation(Ping ping): @annotation(ping);

    pointcut execute() : execution(* * (..));

    Object around(Ping ping) : execute() && hasPingAnnotation(ping) {
        System.out.println("Before method execution");
        String endpoint = ping.endpoint();
        System.out.println("Endpoint = " + endpoint);
        Object result = proceed(ping);
        System.out.println("After");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly well with the ajc compiler!
Hope it can help